# Visual Studio 2019 - change .NET target framework to 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I cannot change the .NET version of my project. I installed .NET 4.8 via the Visual studio installer and manually downloaded it separately. Neither of these works.

I actually tried to change the framework in the .csproj project file

```xml
<TargetFramework> net5.0-windows </TargetFramework>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
```

and it doesn't work too...
I'm running out of solutions and don't really know what to do next.

[image: target framework pic]

Comment: Use the proper project template to get started.  Right now you use one that targets ".NET" or ".NET Core", you need one that targets ".NET Framework".

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is it a compile error?

Comment: if I change it to 4.8 in the .csproj file, I get a compile error and in the project setting I only have version 5.0 or 3.x available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attempting to convert an SDK-style "net5.0-windows" project to a "net48" WinForms one you'll likely need to do more than just change `TargetFramework`.

Firstly, the `Project` node at the start of the ".csproj" file should look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
```

(A "net5.0" target doesn't need the `.WindowsDesktop` part of that.)

Secondly, you'll need to ensure that `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` is part of the main `PropertyGroup`.

Even after those changes you're still likely to get all sorts of issues if your project uses types that are not available in .net 4.8.

Comment: The settings are already like that. I was able to remove WindowsDesktop, after i change the .net Version the compiler said he cannot find the debugfile in projectpath.

Comment: @MartinHe If you create a new project from scratch, does it give you the option to create a .net 4.8 program?

Comment: Yeah,  that works. I also recreated it and copied all of the code over by hand. 

It is not possible to switch from .net core to .net Framework?

Comment: @MartinHe Once you have a new SDK-style project that works, you should be able to change the `TargetFramework` - but you should unload the project before changing it and reload the project afterwards, otherwise it usually gets a bit confused.